# Could I use my old D-link GO-RT-N150 router as a Wifi repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, repeater

I live in a big house and when on one side Wi-Fi doesn't reach. I have an old D-Link GO-RT-N150 router. Could I use it as a repeater?